# How to sort the month list from January to December in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, angular-material, angular7

Browser is sorting the month list by default in alphabetical order.How can I sort it in months order?
Here is the object data in the .ts file :

```
 objdata:{ '2017': 
   { total: 150000,
     data: 
      { January: 1200,
        February: 1200,
        March: 1300,
        April: 1300,
        May: 1200,
        June: 2000,
        July: 5000,
        August: 4000,
        September: 4500,
        October: 1200,
        November: 9000,
        December: 9000 } },
  '2018': 
   { total: 20000,
     data: 
      { January: 1200,
        February: 1200,
        March: 1300,
        April: 1300,
        May: 1200,
        June: 2000,
        July: 5000,
        August: 4000,
        September: 4500,
        October: 1200,
        November: 9000,
        December: 9000 } }
}
```

I am using *ngFor for showing the data :

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of objdata | keyvalue">
      <td scope="row">
        <mat-accordion>
          <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title>
                Year {{item.key}}
              </mat-panel-title>
              <mat-panel-description> 
                  {{item.value['total']}}
              </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <div class="row" *ngFor="let subitem of item.value['data'] | keyvalue">
              <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{subitem.key | titlecase}}</label>
              <label class="col-sm-9 col-form-label">{{subitem.value}}</label>
            </div>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
        </mat-accordion>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

How can I sort this like january,february,march...... and so on?

Comment: what is `keyvalue` filter in `*ngFor`. can u share keyvalue code as well.

Comment: 'keyValue' pipe is used when we have data in form of object of object.

Comment: @anjuboura instead of using a pipe , try to filter it in the .ts file before loading it to the template, also you could use the following article to sort the array : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349331/javascript-sort-items-list-by-months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-e1ghae?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)**

You can create a **pipe** like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "sortMonth"
})
export class SortMonthPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    console.log(value);
    var months = [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    ];
    value.sort(function(a, b) {
      return (
        months.indexOf(a.key) -
        months.indexOf(b.key)
      );
    });
    return value;
  }
}
```

.html

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let subitem of item.value['data'] | keyvalue | sortMonth">
     <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{subitem.key | titlecase}}</label>
     <label class="col-sm-9 col-form-label">{{subitem.value}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: the keyvalue pipe admit as argument a function sort, so you can use `<div class="row" *ngFor="let subitem of item.value['data'] | keyvalue:sort">` where `sort=(a, b) =>  {  return this.months.indexOf(a.key) - this.months.indexOf(b.key) };`, see the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxf6hf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

the keyvalue pipe admit as argument a function sort, so you can use

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let subitem of item.value['data'] | keyvalue:sort">
```

where

```
sort=(a, b) =>  {  
     return this.months.indexOf(a.key) - this.months.indexOf(b.key) 
};
```

see the [Adrita stackblitz forked](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxf6hf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Another aproach is simply get in a const the months

```
months = ["January", "February",...]
```

And iterate over this array:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let month of months">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{month}}</label>
    <label class="col-sm-9 col-form-label">{{item.value.data[month]}}
    </label>
</div>
```

NOTE: In general, we can get the "keys" ordered in a string using regExp like

```
  orderKeys=JSON.stringify(this.myobj)
   .replace(/((:\[(.*?)\])|
             (:{(.*?)})|
             (:\b(\w*)\b)|
             (:\"\b(\w*)\b)|
             {|
             }|\")/g,"").split(',')
```