# how can i sort data in month

Tags: angular, sorting, ionic-framework

i have a function that maping integer to month label

```
// Get month label
  getMonthName(monthNumber: any): string {
    var tempMonth: string;
    let monat = [
      { id: 1, title: 'Januari' },
      { id: 2, title: 'Februari' },
      { id: 3, title: 'Maart' },
      { id: 4, title: 'April' },
      { id: 5, title: 'Mei' },
      { id: 6, title: 'Juni' },
      { id: 7, title: 'Juli' },
      { id: 8, title: 'Aout' },
      { id: 9, title: 'Sept' },
      { id: 10, title: 'Oct' },
      { id: 11, title: 'Nov' },
      { id: 12, title: 'Dec' },
    ];
    monat.forEach((yue) => {
      if (yue.id === monthNumber) {
        tempMonth = yue.title;
      }
    });
    return tempMonth;
  }
```

and then i call it from this function

```
// Get the data from service
  getConso() {
    this.consosrv.getConso().subscribe((tempo: Conso[]) => {
      this.TheConso = tempo;

      //Group data in month
      const groups = this.TheConso.reduce((groups, donne) => {
        const month = new Date(donne.date_achat).getMonth() + 1;
        const MM = this.getMonthName(month);

        if (!groups[MM]) {
          groups[MM] = [];
        }
        groups[MM].push(donne);
        return groups;
      }, {});

      //Mapping data to array
      this.groupArrays = Object.keys(groups).map((mois) => {
        return {
          mois,
          sum: groups[mois].reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b.food_prix), 0),
          donnes: groups[mois].sort(
            (objA, objB) =>
              new Date(objA.date_achat).getTime() -
              new Date(objB.date_achat).getTime()
          ),
        };
      });
    });
  }
```

if i use

```
const month = new Date(donne.date_achat).getMonth() + 1;
```

it work, it sort in integer.

but i want to sort in alphabet

```
const MM = this.getMonthName(month);
```

i implemented your code but it not quite work:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort the month list from January to December in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796100/how-to-sort-the-month-list-from-january-to-december-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you want to sort the groupArrays list by month name, you can do it like so:

```js
 this.groupArrays = Object.keys(groups).map((mois) => {
        return {
         ...
        };
      }).sort((a, b) => a.mois.localCompare(b.mois))
```

As a side note, there are cleaner ways to get the name of the month. For example you can use the function used by date pipe (formatDate) imported from @angular/common or if you're using a library like date-fns:

```js
format(new Date(), 'MMMM', { locale: de })
```

Also, I would suggest avoiding manual subscriptions and going for the async pipe.

**EDIT**

To answer your question from below, if you want to use the month as an integer and display the corresponding month label you can create a custom pipe.

Let's say that your object looks something like this:

```js
{
  monthId: 1,
  sum: ...,
  dones: ...
}
```

Your pipe will be:

```js
// be careful here, if you use the JS month number, you need to start
// indexing from 0
// Ex: 0 month is January
const dictionary: Record<number, string> = {
  1: "Januari",
  2: "Februari",
  3: "Maart",
  4: "April",
  5: "Mei",
  6: "Juni",
  7: "Juli",
  8: "Aout",
  9: "Sept",
  10: "Oct",
  11: "Nov",
  12: "Dec"
};
@Pipe({
  name: "monthLabel"
})
export class MonthLabelPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): string {
    return dictionary[value];
  }
}
```

And you'll use it something like:

```html
<span>{{ payload.monthId | monthLabel }}</span>
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: thanks, but when i use output month in integer like 1,2,3,4.. how can i use pipe to get the label

Comment: @user609511 please see the edited response