# How to sort this object by months?

Tags: javascript

This is my array object:

`arr = {Jun: 25, Jan: 29, Mar: 26, Feb: 24, Apr: 22}`

I want to sort it like this (month wise):
`{Jan: 29, Feb: 24, Mar: 26, Apr: 22, Jun: 25}`

I tried this method:

```
var monthNames = {
  "Jan": 1,
  "Feb": 2,
  "Mar": 3,
  "Apr": 4,
  "May": 5,
  "Jun": 6,
  "Jul": 7,
  "Aug": 8,
  "Sep": 9,
  "Oct": 10,
  "Nov": 11,
  "Dec": 12
};

arr.asort(function (a, b) {
            return monthNames[a[0]] - monthNames[b[0]]
          })
```

But it's not working.

Comment: please change `arr` to a valid data structure.

Comment: Is that an array of strings? Because that's not valid syntax otherwise...

Comment: It's not an array object. It's just invalid syntax. Do you *actually* have an array or not? It's unclear.

Comment: check out this Question-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349331/javascript-sort-items-list-by-months

Comment: I've edited the question. The months are object keys and the numbers are object values.

Comment: you cannot sort the keys inside of a object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot sort the keys inside of a object

and your arr is an object not an array

you can turn it into an array and the sort it

like this

```js
const data = {Jun: 25, Jan: 29, Mar: 26, Feb: 24, Apr: 22}

const monthNames = {
  "Jan": 1,
  "Feb": 2,
  "Mar": 3,
  "Apr": 4,
  "May": 5,
  "Jun": 6,
  "Jul": 7,
  "Aug": 8,
  "Sep": 9,
  "Oct": 10,
  "Nov": 11,
  "Dec": 12
};

const sorted = Object.entries(data).sort((a, b) => monthNames[a[0]] - monthNames[b[0]])

console.log(sorted)
```